# Good resources for learning how to create MSI installers from WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've given up trying to apply lipstick to the pigs of installers that come out of [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) and have decided to look at [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX).

What resources would you recommend to learn and reference?

*(Note - this is not a which-installer-technology-do-you-use question - it's specific to WiX.)*

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow
This is more or less a poll to find the best WiX references

Answer (score 70, accepted):

- The [WiX tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/) is the #1 resource
- The people on the [mailing list](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/mailinglist/) are very helpful
- There's a The Code Project article, *[Creating an installer using Wix v3.0, Votive, and Visual Studio 2005/2008 - Part 2, the GUI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WixTutorial2.aspx)* that might help
- Ther's a bunch of blogs, I keep bumping into [Rob Mensching's (old)](http://blogs.msdn.com/robmen/default.aspx).
- [Rob Mensching's new blog](http://robmensching.com/blog/).
- I haven't read <del>*[WiX - Windows Installer XML](http://www.dalun.com/wix/)*</del> (broken link), but I found it in my bookmarks
- This [code project tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with) outlines the bare minimum and builds up from there

Comment: Rob Mensching (http://stackoverflow.com/users/23852/rob-mensching) is the WiX project lead.

Comment: Thanks for there links

Answer (score 14):

One of the best ways I found to learn WiX was to take an existing MSI that did something I wanted to do, and used the [Dark](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html) decompiler to generate a WiX script from it, and then I read that.

Comment: 'Dark' link is dead mate.

Comment: Couldn't quite find a good replacement link, their docs have changed a lot.

Comment: I second this - using dark this way is in fact a great way to learn Wix and yields a surprising granularity and control for special installation cases such as IIS and similar advanced features. This granularity is actually lacking in other tools since they focus on simplicity.

Answer (score 12):

Apart from the links provided by people above, also have a look at the approach I use to explain this to people :

[image: Wix Commands for creating msi from wix :]

Answer (score 9):

From first glance *[From MSI to WiX](http://blogs.technet.com/alexshev/pages/from-msi-to-wix.aspx)* seems fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 6):

I have to add `wix-users@lists.wixtoolset.org`. That's where everyone hangs out and asks/answers questions as they come up. Just lurking on that mailing list will provide lots of real-time education on the WiX toolset.

Answer (score 6):

Even though it's not only related towards WiX, the book from [Apress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apress):

The Definitive guide to
Windows Installer
By Phil Wilson
[link](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590592977)

It helped me to understand the installation processes. It's a good book to have when writing installers.

Comment: Everyone should read this *before* embarking on understanding WiX

Answer (score 6):

Here's a shameless plug to the book I've recently published through Packt:

[WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://www.packtpub.com/wix-a-developers-guide-to-windows-installer-xml/book)

It covers a lot of what you'd need to know to get going using WiX 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand German, then read the articles in the [Entwickler Magazin](http://entwickler-magazin.de/), edition: 2008-05, 2008-06 and 2009-01.

A follow-up will be published in 2009-02, with more developing stuff (MSI API).

Answer (score 2):

You may use link as a reference https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/
It won't help a beginner as it didn't provide any practical examples.

For a beginner, if you have a pluralsight subscription, there is a course which will teach you the basics.

'WIX-Cookbook' https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/wix-cookbook by Nick-Ramirez (Covers Wix-3.8). This is the book if anyone looking to get the job done quickly.

If you want to gain in-depth knowledge on how and why everything works, you probably better of going through Wix-3.6 A Developers Guide by the same author.
https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/wix-developers-guide-windows-installer-xml

To create an installer for websites, refer following series by Bart De Meyer
http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/
This article will show you how to use Wix tools like Candle and Light.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tutorial that shows you how to create a WIX installer for a console application [here](https://www.bayological.io/Post/How-To-Create-a-Wix-Installer-For-a-Console-Application), if you wanted a practical example.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in with another shameless plug; I recently wrote an article where I somewhat desperately try to explain some of the concepts of WiX in a more easily-understood way than the others. No offence.

http://www.optimalbpm.se/wiki/index.php/WiX

It is meant to be read *before* reading any tutorials, because it specifically tries to address some of the things people always seem to misunderstand as a result of well, reading those tutorials. And especially the documentation. At least I did.

Also, there is another article, a little bit more advanced, that has an angle to those distributing script(like Python etc)-based systems, and why one in not only those, but all cases should use Paraffin rather than Heat.

http://www.optimalbpm.se/wiki/index.php/Wix_and_scripting_languages