# Deployment kit suggestions

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, setup-deployment

I wrote some application under .Net 4.0 and I am looking a way to deploy it.

I am after some kit that will be able to:

- Put my files in some predefined folder,
- Create all needed short cuts
- Insert my application under the programs menu.

Ideally this kit should be free and simple to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely sounds like a job for [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (Windows Installer XML Toolset).

Its a free open source MSI authoring toolkit that is xml based.  It exposes 100% of the functionality of MSI and I've found it to be very useful in the past - it's definitely capable of doing everything that you have stated in your question.

Also as WiX is now widely used, there are plenty of resources available on the web:

- [Official documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/main.htm)
- [Introduction to the Windows Installer XML Toolset (Tutorial)](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/)
- [Good resources for learning how to create MSI installers from WiX (StackOveflow Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310418/good-resources-for-learning-how-to-create-msi-installers-from-wix)

Answer (score 1):

Use either [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) for Windows (or the [Web Deploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) kit for Web)

Answer (score 0):

[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is a good option too.