# Visual Studio 2008 MSI modification

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-deployment

I'm trying to modify an MSI using Visual Studio 2008.  I have the Project with the code as well.  The install has a pop-up where it request for some information but there are no properties I can set in the msiexec command to set it.  I have never done this before and can't really find any help but I basically want to create a property that can be assigned for that pop-up window.  Looking at the project in Visual Studio I don't see any reference to the windows in the MSI installation so not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of setup project is it? Is it a Visual Studio Setup project (.vdproj) or a WiX project (.wixproj)?

Comment: It is a project added into the solution for deployment.  So yes, a .vdproj.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest grabbing [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) and using Dark to decompile your existing MSI into a WiX script. Then you can refer to [Good resources for learning how to create MSI installers from WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310418/good-resources-for-learning-how-to-create-msi-installers-from-wix) for more info. Visual Studio setup projects are deprecated at this point, so migrating this to WiX will be worth your time.

Comment: Well I'm really looking for a Visual Studio solution but thanks for the notice.