# Create MSI from inf and ocx

Tags: windows-installer, ocx, inf

i have ocx and inf file and need to create a msi file. Not sure how to go about it ?

Answer (score 2):

[Creating an MSI Package Using a Visual Studio Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx)

Suggest you look at [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/):

- [Using WiX 3.0 to create an MSI-based installer for Visual Studio project templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/05/21/9634722.aspx)
- [Good resources for learning how to create MSI installers from WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310418/good-resources-for-learning-how-to-create-msi-installers-from-wix)
- [Creating a WiX Based MSI Package Using Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766790.aspx)

Comment: I got to create msi and it runs and drops inf and ocx file in a folder. is that it ? or do i need make inf file run if so how ?

Comment: If you are installing a driver, take a look at this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/driver-install-with-wix.aspx

Comment: This is what i have achieved I created a msi with a .inf and .ocx file with WIX and works charm as an admin user. But when a non admin user logs in and tries to access the same web page, activex component is not loaded, gives me error "please ensure your browser settings allow activex controls ................... ".  Would like someone to post if they faced this scenario. I need non admin and standard users be able to access the link with activex downloaded. I made all the registry changes, for root, machine, current user.